# Why so strange sort in dired mode?

Tags: dired, sorting

windows 10, emacs 26.1, dired+

here `myfolder` in dired mode sort by name (by default):

[image]

Now I want to sort by date (inverse mode). I press `s` and here result:

[image]

why file `new.txt` is above two dots?

The result must be like this (Total Commander):

[image]

Is it possible in Emacs to get same result?

Answer (score 2):

You asked `dired` to "sort-by-date", not "sort-by-date-but-keep-.-and-..-at-the-top". `dired` uses a version of the `ls` utility to do directory listings. Usually either GNU `ls` or its own "ls" in elisp. Sorting is dependent on these versions of `ls`. On Windows, I'd imaging that `dired` is using the elisp `ls`. You'd have to hack that to add the sort you want (either directly or via "advice"). The functionality you want may already even exist, and you can add a switch to `dired-listing-switches`. Take a look at `ls-lisp.el` for the elisp `ls`.

More info about `dired-listing-switches` can be found in the Emacs Manual at [30.1 Entering Dired](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired-Enter.html).

More info about Emacs's emulated `ls` can be found at [G.4 Emulation of ls on MS-Windows](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/ls-in-Lisp.html#ls-in-Lisp).